# Creating an organized excel spreadsheet from Access Queries

Tags: ms-access

I'm having trouble creating a well organized excel spreadsheet using a Report in Microsoft Access. I have around 40 queries I want to be able to export to an excel spreadsheet, and I want to be able to place them exactly how I have the formatted on a report. I'm running into a few problems:

1. Sometimes the title for the query does not show at all.
2. I have a value that must be entered for the queries to work (a date), but it is going to be the same for all queries. Is there a way I can avoid being prompted for the same value 40 times?
3. When I place a query next to another in the report design view, it does not place the values next to it on the spreadsheet.

[image: Example]

What I get when I run the export is on top, and what I want is on the bottom.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For #2: Use a control (a textbox) and enter the date into it. Use that control as your parameter in your query... Everything else we would need to see the SQL and your VBA code.

Comment: Can you explain that a little more? I have a parameter that depends on what the user wants it to be (StartDate), and 20 queries rely on that, but it is the same value for all of those queries.

Comment: [Here](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/filter1.php)

Comment: I don't think you're understanding me. I don't want to have to enter the same exact DateTime 20 times every time I want to export a report to Excel. All my queries ask for "StartDate". Is there a way that I can use the value for the first asked parameter for the subsequent 19 parameters?

Comment: Yes. Did you not see the link? You create a form, put a textbox control on it, prompt the user to enter the start date into that textbox, and use that textbox as your parameter for your start date. What do I not understand?

Comment: I had never used a form before so I didn't understand you until your most recent post.

Comment: No problem. Did the link help you? Do you need more guidance? If you do it once you will see how simple it can be.

Comment: Yeah, once I created the form the link made sense and I got that issue out of the way. Thanks.